# Recyclerview onItemClick not working (no log)

Tags: android

I wanted to implement an OnItemClick on the elements of my RecyclerView and i built an interface on my adapter and I am calling it on my activity, however the click isn't working and there is no errors in the log, so I'm not sure what I'm messing up. It is a Grid Recyclerview, if that affects anything.. The toast doesn't show up either.

my adapter

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Images> mUploads;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;


public ImagesAdapter(Context context, List<Images> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_view_post, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.get().load(mUploads.get(position).getImage_url2()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ImageView imageView;
    LinearLayout view_container;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
        view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }

}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}


public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
}
```

My activity

```
public class ProfileActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ImagesAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_insideprofile);
    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

    mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(ProfileActivity2.this, mImages);
    mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Building_Images");
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ProfileActivity2.this);

 @Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity2.this, "TestMessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Images selectedItem = mImages.get(position);
    final String image_url = selectedItem.getImage_url2();
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity2.this, FullScreenImageActivity.class);
    mainIntent.putExtra("b_image_url", image_url);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `itemView.setOnClickListener` in your viewholder, you have to add:

```
          public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: They don't need to change their adapter constructor -- just adding the last bit will do:  `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: pls let me know whether it helped you or not